# How to syncronize Firefox Addon FastDial

Tags: windows, ubuntu, firefox, sync

i use Fast dial to improve my firefox. Since i use Windows7 as well as Ubuntu on my laptop i would like to syncronize changes on the fast-dial between both OS.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Best regards Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Replace one of your profiles' FastDial extension folder with a link to the other one, or move one to Dropbox and link to it from both profiles.

Comment: by "link" you mean "symbolic" link?

i think i tried this a couple of days ago and it didn't work.

Even if this "syncs" the fastDial settings, it doesn't sync the the shortcuted pages, since these are in the booksmarks.

Comment: You could share the whole profile, then everything would remain in sync - bookmarks, add-ons, history, config, the works.